# What is the difference between ‘born this way’ and ‘born to be’?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What is the difference between **"born this way"** and **"born to be"**?

And I also want to say:

> We were born these ways, we are physically weak.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

*Born this way* - you were "this way" the moment you were born.

*Born to be X* - you were not X when you were born, but are destined to be X as you grow up.  *To be X* often means "planning to do X" or "destined to do X".

> we were born these ways, we are physically weak

Keeping it simple, you can either be *born in these ways* or *born this way*, but not *born these ways*.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that as you grow  up, you are a genius. Some people might say: "He was born that way." And I hope you don't say (because it's sort of narcissistic) "I was born this way." is you are, in fact, a genius.

Now, **born this** way **refers to whatever feature of your personality you care to name or that others care to name about you. Positive or negative.**

If you are born with a cleft palate, and have the operation to fix it, that's great. But in any case, **you were born that way. [with the cleft palate]**

In contrast, **born to be a criminal, an outstanding member of society or just wild**, like the song "Born to Be Wild" means that whatever comes after the to is **your destiny**. It is what you were destined to be.